# Tinymce on tab press make : symbol in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, editor

I am using [tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/) editor, what I want is when user press tab button before: symbol it should be string alignment. For reference please check screenshot.
[image]

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    indentation : '60pt',
    plugins: 'textcolor print preview importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable',
    paste_as_text:true,
    //menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | fontselect fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor backcolor',
    nonbreaking_force_tab: true

});
```

[image]

Comment: I can't exactly understand what you want. Can you explain more about your problem? What do you want to do when the user presses a **single tab** or a **shift tab**? Is this about indentation?

Comment: @ChristosLytras,  when user press single tab

Comment: Can you please create a basic working example of your working instance?

Comment: And what exactly means *before: symbol it should be string alignment*? Is this about the spaces? You want there to be spaces between `Foo 1 : Bar1`?

Comment: @ChristosLytras in TinyMCE try to create a list as I share in that screenshot. We will get the issue.

Comment: @Prince see this fiddle => http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: @c.grey I added the list to the TinyMCE and I press tab and it applies indentation to the list and it changes list item style, but I still can't understand what your problem is. You want different behavior when user presses the tab button?

Comment: @ChristosLytras check out the new screenshot : must in one line.

Comment: tab stops are not really done in html, so having something like this will need some brute force like using css' float and width properties as can be seen in Fez Wrecker answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36933465/502442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the Tab key and add 4 spaces. Check the fiddle for a working example. [Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent)

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
    editor.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 9){
          e.preventDefault();
          tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It works when I press tab, but still, indentation is not a straight line.

Comment: Question is how are you going to implement the logic for it. You might be able to get the text content and do the relevant changes by splitting each line (\n) and : and then identifying the current index of : for each line and the following fist character and implement a logic to add spaces

Comment: So is it achievable

Comment: @c.grey It could be with proper logic. Lets say each node (p) has a key value sort of template. You could catch the node of the current pointer and then get the index of : then get the remainder after dividing it by 4. if the remain is 0 add 4 spaces if not add the remaining number of spaces. This way you could align each tab. But the number of times you hit the tab to align might differ